# Anaconda: Cannot import 'RRuntimeError' from 'rpy2.rinterface'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, rpy2

I am using Anaconda on Ubuntu 20.04.
I have installed rpy2 with `conda install rpy2` in a virtual enviroment (different from base)
When I want to run `from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeError` I get the next error:

```
from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeError
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'RRuntimeError' from 'rpy2.rinterface' (/home/myuser/anaconda3/envs/myenvorment/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py)

Comment: can you add the output of `conda list -n myenvorment rpy2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to use the new rpy2 version (3.x) in which `RRuntimeError` has moved from `rpy2.rinterface` to `rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded`. Instead, use:

```
from rpy2.rinterface_lib.embedded import RRuntimeError
```

See an example in [the latest rpy2 documentation](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/introduction.html) and the [3.0 changelog](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/changes.html#release-3-0-0) which explains that `rpy2.rinterface` was completely rewritten for 3.x version.